# What is Part 97 a part of?

Tags: united-states, legal

The regulations that govern Amateur Radio in the United States are often described as Part 97.

What statute are they a part of? Where can I find other parts of the same law?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The full name is 47 CFR (Code of Federal Regulations) 97.

You can find other parts that radio transmissions are regulated by [on the FCC's website](https://www.fcc.gov/encyclopedia/rules-regulations-title-47).

Comment: You can also find other titles in the Code of Federal Regulations at http://www.ecfr.gov/